# Ошибка "'str' object is not callable" при попытке найти элемент на странице

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
el = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('div.iconTabSheet95_0.PPTSPicture'))
```

При попытке его запуска я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\belkina\source\repos\try_ros\try_ros\try.py", line 25, in <module>
    el = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('div.iconTabSheet95_0.PPTSPicture'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

При попытке поиска элемента на странице с помощью селектора я его нахожу: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему мой код не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените строку:

```py
el = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('div.iconTabSheet95_0.PPTSPicture'))
```

На:

```py
el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.iconTabSheet95_0.PPTSPicture')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!